# How to get rid of WCF Test Client error?

Tags: wcf

I have WCF service and it works in WCF Test Client when use Development Host. But when I use IIS 7 and try to run some method there is an error:

```
The underlying provider failed on Open.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IDatabaseService.GetAllUsersWithRoles()
   at DatabaseServiceClient.GetAllUsersWithRoles()
```

The service communicate with MS SQL Server over Entity Framework. IIS 7 and MS SQL Server are placed on the same machine.

How to make it work?

UPDATE - Here is the content of web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ForisTestLogsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ForisTestLogsModel.csdl|res://*/ForisTestLogsModel.ssdl|res://*/ForisTestLogsModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=GORAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ForisTestLogs;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please provide more information. Have you configured your service in Web.config? If so, post the <system.serviceModel> element as part of your question.

Comment: Please, take a look above at UPDATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration file does not define any service or endpoint. Take a look at the following page on MSDN that explains how you should do this: [Configuring Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932(v=vs.110).aspx)

You will have to add a `<services>` and `<bindings>` element to your Web.config file.

As an alternative you can try simplified configuration which was introduced in .NET framework 4.0: [Simplified Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee530014(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you don't feel like manually editing your Web.config file, try using the Configuration Editor Tool. Simply right-click your Web.config file and select "Edit WCF Configuration" from the context-menu. More information about the tool can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732009(v=vs.110).aspx)